# Record all Registry Values that a Process Reads/Writes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there a way to record all the registry values that a process reads/writes, similar to what Process Monitor does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30624/Asynchronous-Registry-Notification-Using-Strongly):

> Handling WMI Events in .NET
>   --- In order to handle WMI events in .NET, we can use classes from the System.Management namespace. For example, this is a piece of code
>   produced by the WMI Code Creator:
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Management;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
>
> namespace WMISample
> {
>   public class WMIReceiveEvent
>   {
>     public static void Main()
>     {
>       try
>       {
>         //Construct the query. Keypath specifies the key in the registry to watch.
>         //Note the KeyPath should be must have backslashes escaped. Otherwise 
>         //you will get ManagementException.
>         WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery(
>                   "SELECT * FROM RegistryKeyChangeEvent WHERE " +
>                   "Hive = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'" +
>                  @"AND KeyPath = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\.NETFramework'");
>
>          ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
>          Console.WriteLine("Waiting for an event...");
>
>          ManagementBaseObject eventObj = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
>
>          Console.WriteLine("{0} event occurred.", eventObj["__CLASS"]);
>
>          // Cancel the event subscription
>          watcher.Stop();
>          return;
>       }
>       catch(ManagementException err)
>       {
>           MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while trying to receive an event: " + 
>         err.Message);
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Link rot happens. Please sum up or quote the crucial bits right here. Link-only answers are subject to deletion without further notice. Thanks.